# Reading in text file and csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

So i have a text file that is tab delimited that i want to read into R dataframe, and it has **1002127** rows.

In R, i execute the line:

```
df <- read.delim("my_text.txt")
```

And the strange thing was that it only registered a total of **497062** rows in total at the environment tab on the right.

However, if i port over the text file to excel and save it as a csv file, and:

```
df <- read.csv("my_text.csv")
```

It registers **1002127** rows which is correct. I would like to know why does read.delim fell short in the row number?

File snippet:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `read.table` instead of `read.delim`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann because it gives me the error "line 138 did not have 55 elements". In fact it got worse when i specified fill=TRUE in read.table. The number of rows got reduced to 344695

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann you probably have to specify `sep = "\t"` and `header` (if any)

Comment: With text data, the problem is often the presence of line breaks (but without seeing at least a snipppet of your data it's hard to tell). You might try reading in the data thus: `read.table("my_text.txt", header = T, quote = "", sep = "\n", na.string = "")`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I've added a snippet of the data file.

Comment: Can you make that reproducible? And this is definitely not what I'd call a **text** file but a **.txt** file--worlds apart!

Comment: I'd try `readr::read_tsv`. Or use command line tools to look at lines 497061 to 497063  to see if anything is weird with the file around that point.

Comment: If you're getting an error in using read.table, you may have a malformed text file. I've had similar problems when a text field contains my delimiter or the comment character but isn't properly quoted when the data file is created. As a result, the function incorrectly calculates the number of columns in the data. Excel is actually pretty good at figuring out malformed data files, and is good at properly quoting it when it re-saves it.